# Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers. Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, $\exists$ $C(\epsilon)$ such that $ab\leq\epsilon a^p+C(\epsilon)b^q$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers. Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a constant $C(\epsilon)$ such that $ab\leq\epsilon a^p+C(\epsilon)b^q$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.

I'm having some trouble starting this one. I don't know where to go.

Comment: Looks a lot like [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) on a special measure space to me.

Comment: @AlexR I just don't know how to start. I have a vague idea of where to go though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try employing [Young's Inequality for Products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality#Young.27s_inequality_for_products).